# How to click on an image and update the view count?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a simple code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var count = 0;
     function changevar(){
             count = count + 1;
         document.getElementById("viewCount").textContent=count;
      }
  </script>

 <button onclick="changevar()">Add view</button>
 <p>View: <span id="viewCount">0</span></p>
```

I click the button, and the view text is updated! Great.

The problem is when I reload the page, the count goes back to 0.

1) How can I keep the count where it was?
2) And how can I change the button, for an image

```
 <button onclick = ( for something like an image ) </button>
```

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: with a database, or just in that browser? Because if the latter, learn you some https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Didn't understand that why many SO users keep downvoting every questions. Answer of question may look very obvious for you, but It may be lifesaving for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save changes in database like MySQLi or json file

Comment: Can you add more of an explanation? Perhaps how one should go about doing that?

Comment: This isn't an answer .. It's a comment.